# I can be short, occasionally lost, sometimes drawn but never colored

Tags: riddle, word

> You can catch me and hold me but only for a while
>
> Tell someone I am bad and wipe out his smile
>
> I can be saved, I can be wasted
>
> I can be analyzed, I can be tested
>
> I can be taken, rarely seen and can be heard
>
> I can be short, occasionally lost, sometimes drawn but never colored.

Who am I? One word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are:

> Breath.

You can catch me and hold me but only for a while

> Catch your breath after exercise, or hold your breath - but not for too long!

Tell someone I am bad and wipe out his smile

> Telling someone they have bad breath is probably going to dampen their spirits...

I can be saved, I can be wasted

> Save your breath - avoid saying something to which little attention will be paid... Or waste your breath and say it anyway.

I can be analyzed, I can be tested

> Don't drink and drive guys! The breath tester/analyser will find you! (And it's a reprehensible thing to do, regardless)

I can be taken, rarely seen and can be heard

> Take my breath away - it's so cold you can see my breath, here - listen.

I can be short, occasionally lost, sometimes drawn but never colored

> Short of breath, or even breathless. Better draw another breath.

Comment: Way to go. Nicely done.